# Use VRAM (graphics card memory) in pygame for images

Tags: python, pygame

I'm programming a 2D game with Python and Pygame and now I want to use my internal graphics memory to load images to.

I have an Intel HD graphics card (2GB VRAM) and a Nvidia GeForce (4GB VRAM).
I want to use one of them to load images from the hard drive to it (to use the images from there).
I thought it might be a good idea as I don't (almost) need the VRAM otherwise.

Can you tell me if and how it is possible? I do not need GPU-Acceleration.

Comment: Since pygame is a wrapper around SDL, it doesn't use the GPU.

Comment: If you're worried about VRAM, as Joshua pointed out - you'll need to switch library and start to optimize your code. I wouldn't worry about it to much if I were you if you're learning. But if this is a real concern, other libraries such as [pyglet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/image/pyglet.image.Texture.html#pyglet.image.Texture) supports dumping textures and vertex lists into VRAM. They do not come with cushy functions such as collision detection etc. But do have helper functions on sprites (such as rotate, scale, alpha channels) and all `GL_` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your window with the `FULLSCREEN`, `DOUBLEBUF` and `HWSURFACE` flags.

Then you can create and use a hardware surface by creating it with the `HWSURFACE` flag.

You'll also have to use `pygame.display.flip()` instead of `pygame.display.update()`.

But even pygame itself discourages using hardware surfaces, since they have a bunch of disadvantages, like
- no mouse cursor
- only working in fullscreen (at least that's what pygame's documentation says)
- you can't easily manipulate the surfaces
- they may not work on all platforms

(and I never got transparency to work with them).

And it's not even clear if you really get a notable performance boot.

Maybe they'll work better in a future pygame release when pygame switches to SDL 2 and uses `SDL_TEXTURE` instead of `SDL_HWSURFACE`, who knows....

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried using FULLSCREEN, HWSURFACE and DOUBLEBUF, and in my case I still have a cursor, also I don't get any errors if I'm using the flags without FULLSCREEEN (even if I see no decrease in RAM usage). I just found out, that they are working on pygame 2, wich is supposed to use sdl2 to enable gpu support.

Comment: @Twistios_Player Nice. It seems that they improved the support for HWSURFACEs then. Does transparency work for you?

Comment: I am using transparent images, and they are shown correctly. That is my code I am using for the screen: https://codeshare.io/anYL11 (Attention: This Link will expire in 24h)